# VBA Excel, formula referencing another cell with variable address

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I need to insert a simple formula in one cell that references 2 cells below the cell where the formula is inserted into. As I will be inserting this formula in many different places, the "2 cells below" addresses are always changing.

So in cell AB200 for example, I want to insert a formula `=sum(AB202 * TextBox3.Value)`, `TextBox3.Value` being the value of a text box field entered previously in the macro.

The procedure will then be repeated but with a different address and different Text variable.

I am OK with the loop so I just need the VBA code to:

1. write the formula based on a LastRow.Offset(16, 1). position.
2. to code the address of 2 cells below the cell where the formula will be entered and
3. completing the formula with the multiplication of the text variable.

Comment: Would be easier if you'd have shown us the code you have so far... Do you know the R1C1 reference style used in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to reference the cell 2 rows below the one containing the formula:

```
Activecell.FormulaR1C1="=R[2]C"
```

[Read about R1C1 reference style](https://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/) if you are not familiar with that.

For Question 3), add something like this:

```
Activecell.FormulaR1C1="=R[2]C*" & YourTextVariable
```

Hopefully your text variable will actually have a number in it, otherwise you will be trying to multiply a number with a text, which obviously won't work.

As for your question number 1), I have no idea what you mean here. :)
Maybe this?:

```
cells(Activecell.specialcells(xllastcell).Offset(16, 1).row,Activecell.column).FormulaR1C1="=R[2]C*" & YourTextVariable
```

If this is not what you mean, you can either google "last cell VBA", or if you are really lazy, clarify it here so that we can answer.

Comment: Perfect
This answers my question exactly
Thanks

Comment: Hi Vacip,
I don't know what you are talking about when you say I should "mark the question as answered"
I do not see any such option on this page.
Regards
Rob

Comment: Hello @RobD. At StackOverflow, if an answer solved your problem, you can click the tick mark next to the answer to accept it and indicate that your question is solved. [See the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)